# Select SQL query is not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am having trouble with an SQL query that I have inserted into a piece of PHP code to retrieve some data. The query itself works perfectly within SQL. I am using the following PHP script. 
I have the following objectives:

1. Connect to the existing database. This part works well.
2. Get data from the column 'Brand' of the table 'Transport' in `$sql`. This part is not working at this stage. `echo ($sql)` returns `SELECT Brand FROM Transport WHERE Type = 'car'`

Could you please let me know if you see the solution to this issue and if the remaining part of the code is correct. This is my `f_sqlConnect()`

```
function f_sqlConnect() {
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if (!link) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Can not use'.DB_NAME.
            ': '.mysql_error());
    }
}

/*This function cleans up the array to protect against injection attacks */
function f_clean($array) {
    return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
}

<?php
    // Create connection
    $link = f_sqlConnect();

    // Getting data from the column Brand of the table Transport
    $sql = "SELECT Brand FROM Transport WHERE Type = 'car'";

    $result = $link->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Brand: " . $row["Brand"]. "<br>";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    $link->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the function f_sqlConnect() ?

Comment: Try end sql sentece with ";". As: "SELECT Brand FROM Transport WHERE Type = 'car';"

Comment: @hokusai that won't make a difference

Comment: question's too unclear. You state that your connection works but we don't know which API you're using to connect with. You tagged as mysql and sql-server; those 2 are different and use a different API to connect with.

Comment: FYI: I left the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, without seeing your **f_sqlConnect();** mothod. This method should return connection string for DB in your case. But you can use following code this must work.

```
<?php
$servername = "Your_db_host";
$username = "your_db_username";
$password = "your_db_password";
$dbname = "your_DB_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Brand FROM Transport WHERE Type = 'car'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Brand: " . $row["Brand"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**NOTE:** Object oriented way of **mysqli**, You can use procedural way too to connect and get data.

Comment: *"1. Connect to the existing database. This part works well."*

Comment: This is my f_sqlConnect()

Comment: which one? this is means? i did not get your method body

Comment: function f_sqlConnect()
{
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!link)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected)
{
die('Can not use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
}

Comment: dont use mysql, instead of that use mysqli or pdo. mysql is deprecated so use mysqli